# How to access the index values in modal using Django

Tags: python, django, dataframe, modal-dialog

I am trying to access the values of data frame in the modal but the problem is that i am only be able to access the value 1st index in the modal . If I would click the modal of second or third index I am getting the value of first index.

this is my code

```
def form(request):

    #return HttpResponse("form")
    #x = sol_one()
    #file = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/yassa/djangoProjects/first_demo_project/PythonExport.csv')
    #z=file.to_html()
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST["num1"]
        #num2 = request.POST["num2"]
        res,destinations = bigdata(num1)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.to_html(), "html.parser")
        soup.find("thead").find('tr').append(BeautifulSoup('<td>Next Result</td>', 'html.parser'))

        for i in soup.find("tbody").find_all('tr'):
            temp = i.find('th').text
            i.append(BeautifulSoup('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button><div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p></p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div></td>', 'html.parser'))
            #i.append(BeautifulSoup('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button><div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p>'+str(destinations[int(temp)])+'</p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div></td>
            i.find('th')[7].find('p')str(destinations[int(temp)])
            print(destinations[int(temp)])

        #return HttpResponse({"res":res},file.to_html())
        #return HttpResponse(res.to_html())
        #return HttpResponse(soup)
        return checking(request,soup)

        #return render(request,"checking.html",{'res':res})
    else:
        return render(request,"form.html")
```

although all the values are showing properly on console while clicking on the modal but it is repeating the value of first index on all clickable modal.
this is the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Modals have all the same id. Try the Following:

```
def form(request):

    #return HttpResponse("form")
    #x = sol_one()
    #file = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/yassa/djangoProjects/first_demo_project/PythonExport.csv')
    #z=file.to_html()
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST["num1"]
        #num2 = request.POST["num2"]
        res,destinations = bigdata(num1)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.to_html(), "html.parser")
        soup.find("thead").find('tr').append(BeautifulSoup('<td>Next Result</td>', 'html.parser'))
        cnt = 0
        for i in soup.find("tbody").find_all('tr'):
            cnt += 1
            temp = i.find('th').text
            i.append(BeautifulSoup('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal%s">Open Modal</button><div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p></p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div></td>' % str(cnt), 'html.parser'))
            i.find('th')[7].find('p')str(destinations[int(temp)])
            print(destinations[int(temp)])

        #return HttpResponse({"res":res},file.to_html())
        #return HttpResponse(res.to_html())
        #return HttpResponse(soup)
        return checking(request,soup)

        #return render(request,"checking.html",{'res':res})
    else:
        return render(request,"form.html")
```

Comment: You have a typo here `.find('p')str`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes it's copied from above, not sure what he was trying to do here.

Comment: @NicoGriffioen what were you trying to achieve with this: `i.find('th')[7].find('p')str(destinations[int(temp)])`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding multiple modals with the same ID (#MyModal), so when a button is clicked, the first modal with id MyModal will be opened, which contains the data of the first index.

A quick fix would be to use an iterator and give each modal a unique ID, like this:

```
modal_identifier = 0

for i in soup.find("tbody").find_all('tr'):
            temp = i.find('th').text
            i.append(BeautifulSoup('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'+ modal_identifier +'">Open Modal</button><div class="modal fade" id="myModal'+ modal_identifier +'" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p></p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div></td>', 'html.parser'))
            #i.append(BeautifulSoup('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'+ modal_identifier +'">Open Modal</button><div class="modal fade" id="myModal'+ modal_identifier +'" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p>'+str(destinations[int(temp)])+'</p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div></td>
            i.find('th')[7].find('p')str(destinations[int(temp)])
            print(destinations[int(temp)])

            modal_identifier += 1
```

You could also consider adding 1 modal, and using Javascript to fill the modal with the correct data.

Comment: wait let me try this !

Comment: I accidentally added the modal identifier to the commented out modal, so it didn't work. I updated my answer and it should work now.

Comment: @NicoGriffioen you may want to read about [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) ;-)

Comment: Haha, when I wrote this answer a voice in the back of my head said "There is a more pythonic way to do this", but I couldn't for the life of me remember what it was. Thanks!